# Using RotatingFileHandler in python gives permission denied error python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code:**

```
import sys

from flask import Flask
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d [%(thread)d] [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
file_hdlr = RotatingFileHandler('logs/debug_{}.log'.format(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')), maxBytes= 1024, backupCount= 10)
file_hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
file_logger = logging.getLogger('file_logger')
file_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_logger.addHandler(file_hdlr)

@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
def test():
    """
    This function is for testing API
    
    Returns:
        This function returns a string.
    """
    for i in range(25):
        file_logger.info(f"{i}")
    return "API working correctly"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5001, debug = True, threaded = True)
```

**Traceback:**

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.doRollover()
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libr
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file becauUsers\\aniket.bote\\Desktop\\Aniket\\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\\iket.bote\\Desktop\\Aniket\\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\\logs\\deb
Call stack:
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libst_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libt
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 342, in handle
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 374, in handle_one_request
    self.run_wsgi()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 319, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 310, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz_init__.py", line 309, in debug_application
    app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimizine 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimizine 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimizine 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimizine 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.v
  File "c:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz
    file_logger.info(f"{i}")
Message: '23'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.doRollover()
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libr
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file becauUsers\\aniket.bote\\Desktop\\Aniket\\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\\iket.bote\\Desktop\\Aniket\\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\\logs\\deb
Call stack:
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libst_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libt
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 342, in handle
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "c:\users\aniket.bote\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 374, in handle_one_request
    self.run_wsgi()
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 319, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz.py", line 310, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz_init__.py", line 309, in debug_application
    app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimizine 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimiz    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\aniket.bote\Desktop\Aniket\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\app.py", line 33, in test
    file_logger.info(f"{i}")
Message: '24'
Arguments: ()
```

The log file generated contains numbers up to 22. I am trying to create a logger that will create a new log file once the buffer size is reached. The code provided is a standalone code that regenerates the issue.
I am using a windows system.

The same code works if I remove the ***'.log'*** extension from the file

Comment: I am experiencing very same problem. Repeatedly. My log file has log suffix as well. The first file (e.g. testbed.log) works fine. The next rotated file (e.g. testbed.log.2022-06-06.log) fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the traceback, there is this line

`PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file becauUsers\\aniket.bote\\Desktop\\Aniket\\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\\iket.bote\\Desktop\\Aniket\\DS_2021_Array_cable_optimization\\logs\\deb`

This implies that the path is wrong here, which can also be seen from *becauUsers* which is probably not a correct path in Windows. You have to find where it uses this path.

Comment: I have not given any explicit path. As you can see in the code, its just storing the generated generated log file inside logs directory. The code provided is a standalone code. So are you implying there is a problem with providing path as I have provided?

Comment: Most probably. You should try changing that path to different values to find out the exact issue.